# Is there any way to add layout tag using android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm migrating an old android project to use the Android DataBinding library. The first step is adding the layout tag as the root tag of all layout files in the project.

Doing this manually is ready frustrating so I want to ask Is there any way I can do it automatically in Android Studio?

Similar to converting a layout file to use motion layout. Just right click on the layout file and hit the convert to motion layout option.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: CLick here]

Click on the bulb icon on the top and convert to data binding layout as shown in picture that i added

Comment: You're the Man (y)